# VBA - Syntax error with TRANSFORM in SQL statement

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I'm here to ask you for help because, following various experiments with ADO, I have a problem that I can't solve.

I believe I have done everything right but VBA informs me that I have committed a syntax error in transform education

I have checked everything well and I didn't notice mistakes, also because the same query performed on Access works well.

The purpose is that the query returns this result:

[image: Example image]

If I run a very similar query without join I have no problems and everything works but if I use the join on the worksheet "months" the syntax problem emerges.

Would you be so kind to suggest where I'm wrong?

Thank you very much for support.

Here the file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2isoyahnsmvcr2k/Errore_TRANSFORM.xlsb?dl=0

Here my code:

```
Sub generaRicavi()
    Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim conn As String, SQL As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "; Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation =True;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"
            
    SQL = "TRANSFORM Sum(Foglio1$.RICAVI)" _
            & " SELECT Year([Foglio1$].[DATA])" _
            & " FROM MESI$ LEFT JOIN Foglio1$ ON MESI$.MESE =  Month([Foglio1$].[DATA])" _
            & " GROUP BY Year([Foglio1$].[DATA])" _
            & " ORDER BY Year([Foglio1$].[DATA]), MESI$.MESE" _
            & " PIVOT MESI$.MESE;"
            
    RS.Open SQL, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    
    With Foglio2
        .Range("A3").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Range("A3:M3") = Array("ANNO","GENNAIO", "FEBBRAIO", "MARZO", "APRILE", "MAGGIO", "GIUGNO", "LUGLIO", "AGOSTO", "SETTEMBRE", "OTTOBRE", "NOVEMBRE", "DICEMBRE")
        .Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset RS
    End With
    
    RS.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set RS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Side Note: `Range("A3:M3")` is larger than the array you're putting into it, which leads to cell M3 having `#N/A` error value.

Comment: Please add a sample data set to your question - nobody will download your file. Read [ask] and [repro] - this will help you to improve your question

Comment: Your last two dynamically created lines of your SQL will leave no space between `MESI$.MESE` and `PIVOT`. The code essentially created the following string: `"ORDER BY Year([Foglio1$].[DATA]), MESI$.MESEPIVOT MESI$.MESE;"` When running into issues related to dynamically generated SQL, it's often times a good step to output your SQL string to the debug window and then copy/paste into your database and run as-is to see if the same error pops.

Comment: If that doesn't solve the problem, could you also add the exact error message you are getting when you run this code?

Comment: Hi JNevill! The error message is: “ Syntax error with TRANSFORM”

Comment: Hi @JNevill I changed the code as from your suggestion but unfortunately I still continue to find the syntax error message with the transform statement... On Microsoft Access the same query works great so I think it's a writing error of the SQL code on Excel VBA. Can you help me understand what's wrong? Thanks for the support!

Comment: "Syntax Error" often means that the data contains a NULL or invalid data point. Add a where clause to exclude invalid data points.

Comment: If you haven't solved this yet, could you add a `debug.print SQL` line in there and then copy/paste the SQL statement form the `immediate` pane in VBA. Paste that into your Access DB and rerun. Perhaps also paste here too. Something feels like it's going wrong with the creation of that SQL but it's not at all obvious from looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Indeed there were syntax errors in the query. The square brackets between worksheets and table fields were missing.
The code that works is this:

```
Sub generaRicavi()
    Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim conn As String, SQL As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "; Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation =True;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"
            
    SQL = "TRANSFORM Sum(Foglio1$.RICAVI)" _
            & " SELECT Year([Foglio1$].[DATA])" _
            & " FROM [MESI$] LEFT JOIN [Foglio1$] ON [MESI$].[MESE] =  Month([Foglio1$].[DATA])" _
            & " GROUP BY Year([Foglio1$].[DATA])" _
            & " ORDER BY Year([Foglio1$].[DATA]), [MESI$].[MESE]" _
            & " PIVOT [MESI$].[MESE];"
            
    RS.Open SQL, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    
    With Foglio2
        .Range("A3").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Range("A3:M3") = Array("ANNO", "GENNAIO", "FEBBRAIO", "MARZO", "APRILE", "MAGGIO", "GIUGNO", "LUGLIO", "AGOSTO", "SETTEMBRE", "OTTOBRE", "NOVEMBRE", "DICEMBRE")
        .Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset RS
    End With
    
    RS.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set RS = Nothing
End Sub
```